# Element-wise boolean multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for the most beautiful and short way to multiply those types of lists:

```
a = [True, False, True, False, False]

b = [100, 200]
```

Length of **b** *equals to number of True elements* in **a**

The answer that I need is `[100, 0, 200, 0, 0]` here

Are there any simple ways to get that answer?
It looks like element-wise multiplication, but the fact is that the size of the second list is smaller, so common numpy methods don't work without bad code.

Hope, you'll find nice solution

Comment: Your answer that you require is a `list`, but you've tagged this with `numpy`, which generally deals with `numpy.ndarray` objects, two different data-structures with different performance trade-offs/charactersitics. So, which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a pretty clean iterator based solution

```
it = iter(b)
[next(it) if x else 0 for x in a]
# [100, 0, 200, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Probably the best non-`numpy` solution.

Comment: Probably the best solution full stop.

Comment: @Alexander No, it is not the best "full stop". `numpy` based solutions are faster when data are already arrays.

Answer (score 10):

You could do this in `numpy`:

```
c = np.array(a).astype(int)

c[c==1] = b

>>> c
array([100,   0, 200,   0,   0])
```

**Note** If you need the result as a list (based on your desired output), rather than a `numpy` array, use `c.tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use either [`numpy.place()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) or [`numpy.put()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.put.html):

```
c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=np.result_type(b))
np.place(c, a, b)
```

or

```
c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=np.result_type(b))
np.put(c, np.flatnonzero(a), b)
```

I prefer the first option.

#### Timings:

Generate larger data set:

```
In [39]: a = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100000).astype(np.bool_)

In [40]: b = np.random.randint(0, 100000, np.sum(a))
```

@sacul solution:

```
In [41]: %timeit c = np.array(a).astype(int); c[c==1] = b
621 µs ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

My first option:

```
In [42]: %timeit c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=np.result_type(b)); np.place(c, a, b)
462 µs ± 8.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swiping a bit from @AGN above

```
c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype = b.dtype)
c[a] = b
```